# Incremental search in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search in the current document, how do I get automatically navigated to the first search result while I am typing?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> instead. That opens a slightly different window with the incremental search behavior you want.

Comment: Hm, does not navigate me at all, if I am topmost in an editor and start typing, I can´t even navigate to it by pressing enter.

Comment: Hmm... strange. Works for me. But you do get the (slightly smaller) search window when you press CTRL+I?

Comment: yes, it is a bit different

Comment: Could it be that you have some extension installed that broke your editor? Have you tried restarting VS?